# Finding physical path in C# .net

Tags: c#, winforms

```
@"F:\LEAFPRODUCT\Bin\Service.exe"
```

This is the physical path of `Service.exe`, let me know is there any other alternate way or any general way to find the physical path of `WrmService.exe` in window application.

In a web application we can use `Server.MapPath` like that. Here I need to reduce path means

```
label1.Text = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"F:\LEAFPRODUCT\Bin\Service.exe").Version.ToString();
```

This is my coding I need to reduce the physical path here, means I don't want to put all the folders I need this way only

```
label1.Text = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("WrmService.exe").Version.ToString();
```

means only the required file name here means `WrmService.exe`

Answer (score 8):

`System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()` is similar as `Server.MapPath()`

You can give it a relative location, and it will give you the full location based on the directory that the assembly is in.

Comment: means

label1.Text = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"F:\LEAFPRODUCT\Bin\Service.exe").Version.ToString();

this is my coding i need to reduce the physical path here ,,means i dont want to put all folders i need this way only label1.Text = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("WrmService.exe").Version.ToString(); means only the required file name here means WrmService.exe

Comment: here relative location means?

Comment: ..\SomeFolder\Bin\Some.exe will translate into C:\Code\SomeFolder\Bin\Some.exe like Server.MapPath will take ~\Some.exe into C:\Code\SomeFolder\Bin\Some.exe

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

- [C#: How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/c-how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Answer (score 0):

You want the physical path of the executable assembly?

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

Comment: But this will give the assmbly location of current page only,,i want to get location of a particular assemly from a different page

Comment: What do you mean by "page?" A Windows Service is not an ASP.NET app.