# Creating a new directory for log event file in windows service in c#

Tags: c#

I am wondering on how to create a new directory for a log event file in windows service through c#

I have the following code:

```
public static void WriteLog(string Message)
{
    StreamWriter sw = null;
    try
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\DataFile.txt", true);
        //sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "C:\\MulpuriServiceLOG\\data.txt", true);

        //sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + Message);
        sw.WriteLine(Message);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Comment: Hope that you should Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

As the [docuemtation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) states for the `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)`:

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist.

Modified from the [example source code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx):

```
string path = @"c:\MyDir";

try 
{
    // Try to create the directory.
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
} 
finally {}
```

There is a really great tutorial on [dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/directory-createdirectory) containing example code, exceptions, tips and other useful information about creating directories!

Look up [that SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343206/how-to-create-a-folder-in-the-application-installed-directory) to create folders inside the same directory your executable has started, or simple use [relative paths instead of absolute ones](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/):

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("Test");
```

That way you will never have conflicts about finding the correct path!

Answer (score 0):

```
    File yourFolder= new File("C:/yourFolder");

    // if the directory does not exist, create it
    if (!yourFolder.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Creando directorio: " + yourFolder.getName());
        boolean result = false;

        try
        {
            yourFolder.mkdir();
            result = true;
        } 
        catch(SecurityException se){

        }        
        if(result) {    
            System.out.println("Folder created");  
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess this is java code? The OP asked for c# code.

Comment: Im sorry, i understand bad

Comment: strikar tagged the question `C#`, so i do not think that java code would be helpful.