# Determine assembly location

Tags: .net, reference, assemblies, directory, location

I have project called A, located in C:\ProjectA.
It references a dll called B.dll, located in C:\Binaries.

Now B.dll has to dynamicly load a second DLL called C.DLL which is in the same folder (C:\Binaries). But how can B determine C's location?

I know about AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory and Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, but both will return 'C:\ProjectA\', because B.dll was loaded by A.exe.

I know the obvious solution would be to place all binaries in the same folder, and they will be when released, but while developing I cannot change the repositry's layout, and I want to avoid to hardcode the paths.

Edit: Sorry duplicate of [How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/c-how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx) from B? This will return The Assembly object of the method that invoked the currently executing method. (ie B)

```
public void BMethod()
{
     var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
     string path = assembly.Location;
      //now use this path to load C.dll in the same folder.

}
```

see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/c-how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in) similar stack overflow question

Comment: Thanks! My question seems to be a duplicate when i look at that question :o

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly.aspx), you have to test it based on some type existing in C (or B):

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(yourVar.GetType());
//your location will be in assembly.Location
Console.WriteLine("Location=" + assembly.Location);
```