# Get file path of the current class library in Windows Mobile 6 CE from the solution

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I'm trying to retrieve the current path of a file from a project in windows mobile 6 application. I've tried using

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
```

This doesn't retrieve the file path I'm looking for as the file I'm calling is in a different Class library of the solution. Can anyone help me out in retrieving the file path for the class library of the solution which isn't the executing assembly.

Thanks,
Vinod.

Comment: How's http://stackoverflow.com/a/52956/555547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeof(SomeType).Assembly.GetName().CodeBase`, where `SomeType` is any type in the desired DLL.

Comment: what does a type in the dll mean?

Comment: Any type defined in that library.

Comment: I'm trying to load an xslt using  xslTransformer.Load("path");
the project has a folder called content which has the .xslt file.How do I load this path?