# Visual Studio 2008 add-in cannot load external text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, add-in

I'm currently working on a simple add-in that is supposed to insert a copyright statement to a source file. It works fine but i would like the copyright text to live in a text file. This text file is being deployed to the same folder as the dll and .AddIn file.

But since the add-in could be installed in different folders on different machines the problem is now that I have not been able to figure out how to get the path to the text file programatically from the add-in code (c#). I've tried all kinds of reflection methods but non have worked so far.

If this is not possible or not the right approach please let me know what alternatives I have besides hardcoding the copyright text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text file is always in the same folder as the dll, then I think this related question should help you:

[How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Comment: Thanks, i had missed that one. One of their suggestions worked.