# Get actual dll path in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll

I have a dll named JIMS.Printing.dll which is placed inside the Reporting folder of the main application JIMS.exe.

But I am getting an error when calling some files inside the Templates folder inside JIMS.Printing.dll code inside of Reporting which running JIMS.exe

```
JIMS.exe
--------->Reporting
------------------->JIMS.Printing.dll
------------------->Templates
-----------------------------> Files
```

Code:

```
string _templatePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(JIMS.Printing.PrintInvoice)).Location), "Templates");
```

Code from JIMS.Printing.dll

JIMS.exe looking for Files inside JIMS.exe Path\Templates\file,
But actually the file is in JIMS.Printing.dll Path\Templates\files

Comment: What is the error? What is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

which will give you the path of the executing assembly then use:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

which will give the containing folder.

Comment: You may also want to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/283917/1306012

Answer (score 2):

YOu can try this:-

```
 string path1= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DaoTests)).Location;

 string directory= Path.GetDirectoryName( path1 );
```