# Could not find a part of the path?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, io

I have the following code :

```
fileinfo = new FileInfo(filePathAndName);

if (!fileinfo.Exists)
{
    using (xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filePathAndName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("root");
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("objects");
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

The filePathAndName will be `C:/MyApp%205/Produkter/MyApp%20Utveckling/Host/Orbit.Host.Dev/bin/ExceptionLog.xml.`

The folder does exists but the file does not. XmlTextWriter should in this case create the file but instead it throws `Could not find part of the path`.

It's probably something very obvious I have forgotten here, please help.

Edit : This is how the path really looks like :

```
C:\MyApp 5\Produkter\MyApp Utveckling\Host\Orbit.Host.Dev\Bin
```

And this is how the URL that is used in the code is generated :

```
 (new System.Uri(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase) + "\\ExceptionLog.xml")).AbsolutePath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried the code, `ArgumentException` is thrown by `XmlTextWriter` constructor with this message:

> the URI formats are not supported.

Consider the following code:

```
// Get the path to assembly directory.
// There is a lot of alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/
var assemblyPath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);

// Path to XML-file.
var filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, "ExceptionLog.xml");

using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -- add @ before the filePathAndName

```
string filePathAndName = @"C:\MyApp 5\Produkter\MyApp Utveckling\Host\Orbit.Host.Dev\Bin\text.xml";

FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filePathAndName);

if (!fileinfo.Exists)
{
    using (XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filePathAndName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("root");
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("objects");
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interacting with a path on a network (aka UNC path), you have to use Server.MapPath to turn a UNC path or virtual path into a physical path that .NET can understand.  So anytime you're opening files, creating, updating and deleting files, opening directories and deleting directories on a network path, use `Server.MapPath`.

Example:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("\\server\path"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`Uri.AbsolutePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx) you should take [`Path.Combine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)

```
var filepath = @"C:\MyApp 5\Produkter\MyApp Utveckling\Host\Orbit.Host.Dev\Bin"
var filename = Path.Combine(filepath, "ExceptionLog.xml");

var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);

if(!fileInfo.Exists)
{
    //ToDo: call xml writer...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Assembly.Location and Path.Combine to form your fileNameAndPath variable:

```
var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var filePathAndName = Path.Combine(folder, "ExceptionLog.xml");
```