# How to get assembly path at runtime, running either in webserver, service or win app

Tags: c#, reflection, resources

I have a Resource project I use for various parts of our products. To make it more flexible I decided to place the .resx externally from the dll processed with the resgen tool, to allow users to add their own language files on the fly. Since the project will be accessed from various places, web, service or stand-alone winForm, how can I get the path of where the .dll is located so that I can supply the correct path for

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                temp = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("Resources", cwd, null); 
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
```

I can hardcode the path and it works great, though I would rather have it figure out the path at runtime.

I tried something like this, however it did not work

```
string fullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Resources)).Location;

//get the folder that's in
string theDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath); ResourceManager temp =

"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) on disk.
```

baseName: Resources  locationInfo:   fileName: Resources.resources"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following to work from

[How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
var theDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```