# SQL Server CE Connection string to connect to the database from a windows form application

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

```
SqlCeConnection conn =
   new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source= " + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\ITIA.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"));
conn.Open();
```

this is my code and it is showing me the following error:

> The file name is not valid. Check the file name for the database. [ File name = file:\C:\Users\Prash\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ITIA\ITIA\bin\Debug\ITIA.sdf ]

but in the folder the database is saved as ITIA.

I want to publish my windows form application so that the client can enter data which can be stored in a database.

Comment: Where is it saved to? (The *exact* location). How does this differ from what is above?

Comment: I didnt really get you?

Comment: See reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in