# function has stopped working" Error in running the code

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application which works with text file data sets that I tried to make portable (ie: To run the application from external hard drive or pen drive does not need to copy the data sets into the C:\ drive directly.

I changed

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\dataset.txt");
```

into

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("dataset.txt");
```

and copy the dataset into the exe file path `(.../bin/debug)`
But it shows an error `"function has stopped working"`!
Any idea?

Comment: Where does the error appear?

Comment: It is not a code error. the Operation system shows that. but when i copy the data sets into C drive, it works @SLaks

Comment: StreamReader's path value is not relative if I remember correctly. You would need to get the executing assembly's location and then append the filename onto that.

Comment: thank you @Logarr. May you clear your answer with a comment,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of how you can get the absolute path to your executable file:

```
static public string AssemblyDirectory
{
    get
    {
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    }
}
```

*Sample taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283917/1127924)*

If you implement this property you can then update your code to the following:

```
StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader(AssemblyDirectory + "dataset.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks @Logarr. But when I run it. I get the same error.

Comment: I'll need more specifics then. How large are your data files? Are you still trying to run this from within `bin/debug`? Have you set a breakpoint and stepped into the code to confirm the problem is with this line of code?

Comment: The data sets are around 2.5 GiG. Yeap, I am still trying to do it within the same path @Logarr

Comment: And that's the same 2.5 GB file that worked when you put it directly on the C: drive?

Comment: @user3403967 - Sorry I haven't gotten back to you. Did you solve the problem?