# Getting the relative directory of a folder in bin/debug in VB

Tags: vb.net, directory

I am currently working on a windows Application project. I have a folder named "documents" in bin/debug that contains subfolders while the subfolders contains word document files.
When I click and drag the "documents" folder, i got a complete C:\Users\Satellite\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsExplorer_VB\WindowsExplorer_VB\bin\Debug\documents. What I want is to get the location of the folder in bin/debug so that the application can read from the directory when installed on a different machine..
Any help...

Comment: there wont be a `bin\debug` folder on another machine when deployed...those are VS development folders

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Comment: Then how can I return the path of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim docPath As String = Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "documents")
```