# Save files to install directory instead of desktop after installing published C# win forms desktop app

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, installshield, publish

In my win forms C# app, I am exporting my images to pdf and word. Before export, images need to be saved as bitmap. Did it like this:

```
// code
bitmap.Save("Image.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bitmap.Dispose();
```

Now the code for word and pdf export read this file normally from saved location. Howewer, while I was testing my desktop app, code `"Image.jpeg"`saves image to bin directory.

When I made installer using InstallShield and installed my program, this option works but it save my image to desktop. I don't really want that.

Managed to send it to ApplicationData directory but don't want that either...

```
string imageSaved = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Image.jpeg");
bitmap.Save(imageSaved, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bitmap.Dispose();
```

How to navigate my file to installation directory?

Comment: It is not a good idea to save your files in the same folder where your app is installed. Usually the OS prevents via permissions writing in this folder.

Comment: so your advice is to leave it in AppData directory? This image is only used as a link untill user save file as .pdf or .docx. Should I programatically delete it after use?

Comment: 1) Yes and 2) probably yes

Comment: Ok. Thans for advice :)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in) will give your all the possibilities, but as I have said, it is best to continue using AppData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`Application.StartupPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the path for the executable file that started the application,
>   not including the executable name.
>
> The path for the executable file that started the application. This
>   path will be different depending on whether the Windows Forms
>   application is deployed using ClickOnce. ClickOnce applications are
>   stored in a per-user application cache in the C:\Documents and
>   Settings\username directory.

For example you can use it this way:

```
string imageSaved = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Image.jpeg");
bitmap.Save(imageSaved, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

For ClickOnce applications, you can use [`ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.datadirectory(v=vs.110).aspx), for more information, see [Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yes i understood but need to check how will it work first... thank you for reply

Comment: this works, but it does not save image to any of these locations and i can't find saved image. When i run debugger it's in the bin folder, before deploy and instalation

Comment: no exception becouse it works well. I save my file as image and get it to pdf i just don't know "Image" location after create. When i run debbuger before i create installer, it goes in bin folder, but when i install my application it does not go to installation directory, documents, desktop, anywhere...

Comment: @dodoria1992 it is placed where you saved it, if you are using `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Image.jpeg")`, then see what is your `Application.StartupPath` and find it there. for example, after saving the image simply do `MessageBox.Show(Application.StartupPath)`

Comment: yea.. show up install directory location but does not display image...
it is probabily becouse of what Steve said above... anyway thanks for your time and effort :)

Comment: @dodoria1992 the reason it does not show up is likely [UAC Data Redirection](http://superuser.com/questions/425513/windows-7-locked-files-folders/425535#425535) if you are trying to write to a protected folder.

Comment: you are right, i found it in **%LOCALAPPDATA%** folder. Thanks alot! :)