# get filename of AssemblyName-object

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

Following code iterates over all referenced assemblies of MyAssembly.dll. How can I output the physically filename of the referenced assemblies? So how can I get the filename of an AssemblyName-Object?

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\MyAssembly.dll");
foreach (AssemblyName lRefAsm in myAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
   ...
}
```

E.g. the ToString()-method of AssemblyName only outputs things like this:

```
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

An I don't find any property which gives me the filename.

Comment: Please try the Assembly.Location property

Comment: You want to get the chicken before the egg is laid.  That's a pretty bad idea, assemblies are only loaded when they are necessary.  By the jitter when it just-in-time compiles a method.  Don't do this.  Also never ever use Assembly.LoadFile(), always LoadFrom().

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get the value of the [`Location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        foreach (AssemblyName lRefAsm in myAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            Assembly ass = Assembly.Load(lRefAsm.FullName);
            string codeBase = ass.CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        }
```

I copied some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in).

Comment: This does not work in all cases. If lRefAsm.FullName is "System.Messaging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" the path will be a reference to Version 4.0.0.0 -> "C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Messaging/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Messaging.dll"

Comment: @user1027167 This is the GAC location, why wrong? Then what does the right path look like?

Comment: In the example above I am requesting the version 2.0.0.0, but the return value is the newest version on my system which is 4.0.0.0. I think Assembly.Load() always returns the newest version on the system.