# Getting DLL's 'Content' file from web app

Tags: c#

I have a class library that has some text files with Build Action = Content. These text files are read by a function within the class library. To get the location of the text files I use this:

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    "AFolder",
    "textFileName.txt");

var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

I have successfully retrieved the content of the text file when I called the function from a unit test. The text file is in `C:\MySolution\MyProject.Test\bin\Debug\AFolder\textFileName.txt`.

I have another web app that references this class library. When I called the function to read the text file from the web app, it couldn't find the text file because it tried to get the file from `C:\MySolution\MyProject.Web\AFolder\textFileName.txt` while the text file is actually in `C:\MySolution\MyProject.Web\bin\AFolder\textFileName.txt`.

So my problem is calling AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory doesn't always work. What should I use instead to get the folder location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer from the [link on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24249706/196451) by using `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase`:

```
var libPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    new Uri(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
    ).LocalPath
);

var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    libPath,
    "AFolder",
    "textFileName.txt");

var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `System.WebHttpRuntime.BinDirectory` to get the physical path to the /bin directory for the current application.

**EDIT 1:**

Another way to get without using System.Web is using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath`, this [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath(v=vs.110).aspx) provides list of directories under the application base directory that are probed for private assemblies.

Comment: I need to add reference to System.Web to my class library? I'd rather not do that if I can. The class library needs to be able to run outside of the web app.