# Get the .trdx location path inside the custom function dll file

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have created a custom function for multilingual support. Inside this function I use path of the language files as an variable. But when I call Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() , System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory or other methods to get the report template file location it always returns the path of the 'TelerikReportDesigner.exe' and where the dll file resides (C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Reporting Q1 2016\Report Designer). But my template file resides on another folder(ex:- E:\Reports..) How can I get the template file location inside the custom function???

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase ? The full code sample can be referenced here: [How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)