# How to get current physical path of a reflected assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an executable that loads another class library DLL using reflection. Within that class library, I want to find out what the physical path of the class library is. I don't want the executing assembly, as that is the original executable.

Eg the exe might be in c:\program\ and the class library might be c:\libraries\remote\Assembly1.dll

Within a method inside Assembly1.dll I need to call something that returns me

> c:\libraries\remote\

I have tried

```
  var currentLocation = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType()).Location;
```

But that doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Comment: That talks about GetExecutingAssembly which is not what I want.

Comment: You can use this approach on any `Assembly` object. It does not matter where you got it from.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to get the current class's assembly path:

```
var dllPath = new Uri(this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way I do it. 
"assembly" is the loaded dll

```
assembly.Location.Replace(assembly.GetName().Name + ".dll", "")
```