# Path of a folder inside my project

Tags: c#, path, resources, directory

So I'm trying to find a way of accesing the path of the folder to copy files but I can't find a way to do it

```
string folderpath = "C:\Users\Marc Vila\Downloads\Version 3.5\WindowsForm1\WindowsForm1/Resources";
```

I don't want to do that because as soon as I move it it gives me an error, anyone knows a more efficient way to do it?
Thanks and regards

Note: I've tried System.IO but it gives me a lot of trouble

Comment: What "error"?  What "trouble"?  You're assigning a string value to a variable, nothing more.  What/where is the actual problem?

Comment: Copying to a project forlder at runtime wont make them available via Resources, if that is what you are trying.  Posts like this give us *a lot of trouble*

Comment: not sure if these are the issues: 1. missing the escape sign, 2. missing the "\" at the end, 3. "/" in the path, typo?

Comment: So my problem is that calling a folder by fullpath works on my computer, but if i send this to someone that won't work because they will have another path to their resource folder, I'm trying to get a 'general' way to call my resource folder without naming the WHOLE path.

Comment: Sorry if my post gave you a lot of trouble, I'm just trying to get things figured out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the assembly's path and then build a relative path on top of that.

Take the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283917/573218) and then use that to combine the paths:

```
var folderPath = Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, "Resources");
```