# Scheduler can't find Environment.CurrentDirectory for a running console app

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have simple C# console app that gets data from `config.ini` located in same directory. Reference to `config.ini` implemented with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`:

```
IniFile myIni = new IniFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\config.ini");
```

Problem is when I'm running app with `Scheduler`, it can't find path to `config.ini`. How to set such path for running app with `Scheduler`?

Comment: Task Scheduler actions have a "start in" setting - have you tried setting it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in for 101 suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

```
// to get the location the assembly is executing from
//(not necessarily where the it normally resides on disk)
// in the case of the using shadow copies, for instance in NUnit tests, 
// this will be in a temp directory.
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

//To get the location the assembly normally resides on disk or the install directory
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;

//once you have the path you get the directory with:
var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Comment: There are better ways for a console app to do this than to include the Windows.Forms assembly...