# Cannot create directory: System.UnauthorizedAccessException Error

Tags: c#

I am relatively new to using files and creating directories in C#, but I have been stuck for a while. I receive the following error: *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Skyroom' is denied.'*

Here is my code in case it helps:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Skyroom\gamedata.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Game loading. Please wait..");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Game loading. Please wait...");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Game loading. Please wait.");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Game loading. Please wait..");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Game loading. Please wait...");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.Clear();

            }
            else
            {                
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\Skyroom");
                File.Create(@"C:\Program Files\Skyroom\gamedata.txt");
                Main();
            }
```

Thank you. Any info needed, just ask.

Comment: Your app just have no access to destination folder.

Comment: Try to run your app or visual studio as an Administrator

Comment: Do not run your app as administrator; that is unnecessary and opens security holes. If you want to save user data [save it in a user folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671590/22437).

Comment: First of all **do** ask a question! Don't let us guess what you try to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that error because your app isn't running as administrator and is trying to write to Program Files which is for admins only.

**Unless you're writing an installer, your application will never need to run as administrator so it can write to Program Files.** Program files is not intended for applications to write runtime data to. It's a secure location intended for an administrator to install applications into. This process protects trusted application files from being maliciously changed.

You should *not* be writing your data to the ProgramFiles directory. Windows has a variety of directories for writing data to, such as %TEMP%, %APPDATA%, and %LOCALAPPDATA%.

[Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows)

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback. I replaced it with %APPDATA% and everything is working. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the windows user you are running the application under does not have permission to the folder `C:\Program Files\Skyroom\`.

You have a few options. One is to grant read/write permissions to the user at the time you create the directory:

```
var skyroomDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\Skyroom");

DirectorySecurity security = skyroomDirectory.GetAccessControl();
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"MYDOMAIN\JohnDoe", 
                        FileSystemRights.Modify, 
                        AccessControlType.Allow));
skyroomDirectory.SetAccessControl(security);

File.Create(@"C:\Program Files\Skyroom\gamedata.txt");
```

Using the appropriate AccessControlType(s) for your needs. You should use the least amount of privilege necessary to perform the necessary tasks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?view=netframework-4.7.2

Another option is to save the file in a user folder that the user will have permissions to. But the issue is a user will see a weird file and possibly delete it.

Answer (score 2):

According to **[File.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.7.2)**, An UnauthorizedAccessException means one of 2 things:

1. The caller does not have the required permission.
   -or-
2. path specified a file that is read-only.

For **[Directory.CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2)**, it means:

1. The caller does not have the required permission.

I wouldn't create a directory under Program Files or Program File x(86). It is advisable to create under like C:\Users\ where you will have permissions.

If still need to create in program files, run visual studio as Administrator or change your manifest like below:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```