# How to set SetBasePath to dll location on Program.Main

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When starting dotnet dll

```
 cd /
 dotnet /tmp/donetproject/donetproject.dll
```

the code

```
.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true)
```

will look at

> /hostsettings.json

not

> /tmp/donetproject/hostsettings.json

setting the GetCurrentDirectory has no effect

```
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

---

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to the set the [location of the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in), not the location of your current workdirectory. That said, its probably better to set the workdirectory to the assembly directory, e. g. `cd /tmp/donetproject/`

Comment: thanks .SetBasePath(AssemblyDirectory) works

Comment: can you add you add Answer so i will accept it here the code https://gist.github.com/Elrashid/1d8859d961b5035af66c11515db460e4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are currently setting the work directory

```
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

This is the directory, where you start the process `/`, more specificaly `cd /`. The directory you realy want, is the [directory of your assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52797/2441442):

```
.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
```

Probably you should consider to change you working directory to the directory of your application instead, e. g. `cd /tmp/donetproject/`.

Comment: The problem with changing the working directory eg cd /tmp/donetproject/ is that it is inconvenient.  I frequently test console apps by just dragging the exe to a console window which calls the exe using the full path. Automation scripts also frequently use full paths. Getting the directory of the assembly means the application can be called from anywhere.