# C#: Starting referenced console applications from an MSIX bundle

Tags: c#, .net-core, msix

I'm working on creating an app that starts three other applications:
`_proc1 = Process.Start(path)`  then checks to make sure they are alive with a Timer object.

This works, so long as I know the absolute path. I can't seem to find out how to do this when the app is installed with an MSIX bundle. All four applications (the startup app, and 3 children applications) are bundled in the app.

I've attempted to Google search this problem away, but I can't seem to find the answer. Your time and expertise are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all executables are installed to a fixed folder layout relative to the calling app, (or even simpler if in the same folder), you can get the absolute path of the folder of the starting app using the answer to [How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in), then construct the paths to the child apps from that.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. I used the following line to get the app to start:

```var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("StartingAppName", "NewAppName") + "NewAppName.exe";
_startMe = Process.Start(dir);```